# Abstract on the title page in LaTeX

Tags: formatting, sharelatex, abstract

I would like the abstract on the title page in the following style:
1. The word 'Abstract' centred above the text
2. A horizontal line immediately underneath the word 'Abstract', with a width equal to that of the text
3. A horizontal line of that same length immediately underneath the text
4. The word 'Keywords:' at the left-side that allows me to put some keywords specific to the thesis.

I have been trying to get this right, but apparently I am missing something. Thanks for the help! Current code can be found here:

```
\renewenvironment{abstract}
{\begin{quote}
\noindent \rule{\linewidth}{.5pt}\par{\bfseries \abstractname.}}
{\medskip\noindent \rule{\linewidth}{.5pt}
\end{quote}
}
```

Picture of the end result I aspire:

[image]

Comment: You realize that the quote environment adds extra margin to the left and right?

Comment: @JohnKormylo I did not know that. However, after removing 'quote' it lead to a less desire result, so I like the style it gives.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the ONLY thing quote does is change the margins.  Unless you are using some other document class.

Comment: You should decide where to ask. Either here or on LaTeX.org.  Once again, you post a snippet, you do not give any indication which document class you are using, alas, you are never posting a suitable MWE. And what does the question have to do with {sharelatex}?

Comment: A [former question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427683/need-help-in-creating-this-thesis-title-page) of yours asked for a title page that seems to contradict with this newer question. If the old question is obsolete, please either delete it or mark as duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

A solution based on `tabularx`, `threeparttable` and `xparse` for the keywords: it defines the abstract as a threeparttable – the abstract itself being a single row of a `tabularx` environment, and the list of keywords, input as an optional argument of the environment, inserted as a table note.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx, threeparttable, booktabs}
\usepackage{xparse} 
\title{Some Title}
\author{Some One}
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{abstract}{o}%
{\small\noindent\threeparttable\tabularx{\linewidth}{@{}>{\arraybackslash}X@{}}\bfseries\centering \abstractname\tabularnewline\addlinespace[1.5ex]\midrule\addlinespace[1ex]}%
{\endtabularx\vspace{-2ex}\hrule\IfNoValueF{#1}{ \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft, online]\smallskip\item[Keywords: ] #1
\end{tablenotes}}
\endthreeparttable\vspace*{6ex}}%

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}%[small $\beta$s, Fama-MacBeth two-pass procedure; foreign currency portfolios; factor pricing; stochastic discount factors; weak identification; principal components]
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\lipsum[2-8]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It might help to look at the definitions is the base folder (article.cls for example).

Since `\rule` expands in hmode, it always takes up `\baselineskip`, while `\hrule` expands in vmode and adds NO extra  vertical space.  The center environment add extra space at the end, which can be removed using `\unskip`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only

\renewenvironment{abstract}
{\begin{center}\bfseries \abstractname
  \end{center}\unskip
  \smallskip\hrule\smallskip\par}%
{\medskip\hrule\smallskip}

\begin{document}
%\begin{titlepage}
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\noindent\lipsum[2]
%\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 1):

I said it [before](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=105477#p105477) and I will say it again: There is no need to redefine the abstract environment.

[image: seanTitlepage]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Masters/Doctoral Thesis 
% LaTeX Template
% Version 2.6 (26/4/18)
%
% This template was downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Version 2.x major modifications by:
% Vel (vel@latextemplates.com)
%
% This template is based on a template by:
% Steve Gunn (http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/srg/softwaretools/document/templates/)
% Sunil Patel (http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/thesis-template/)
%
% Template license:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[
english, % ngerman for German
chapterinoneline, % Uncomment to place the chapter title next to the number on one line
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\chaptermarkformat}{\thechapter\space}
\ihead{\headmark Author p X}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    {\centering
    {\scshape\LARGE Columbidae University \par}
    \vspace{1cm}
    {\scshape\Large Final year project\par}
    \vspace{1.5cm}
    {\huge\bfseries Pigeons love doves\par}
    \vspace{2cm}
    {\Large\itshape John Birdwatch\par}
    \vfill
    supervised by\par
    Dr.~Mark \textsc{Brown}

    \vspace{1cm}\textbf{Abstract}\par}
    \noindent\raisebox{.5ex}{\rule{\linewidth}{.4pt}}\par
    \blindtext\par
    \noindent\raisebox{.5ex}{\rule{\linewidth}{.4pt}}\par
    \noindent Keywords: Alpaca, Wombat, Capybara

    \vfill
    {\centering\large \today\par}
\end{titlepage}
\chapter{Wombat}
\blindtext[10]
\appendix
\addchap{Appendix}
\end{document}
```